# Surya Kala and Chandra Kala in terms of breadth

Tags: chakras

My 101+ year old mother says that breathing through the right nostril is Sura Kala and breathing through the left nostril is Chandra Kala. Is this true?

She also says that breathing through the middle (she did not explain clearly - how one does this) is the best and very few people know how to do this, do you have any comments?

She was trying to explain how this is tied to the chakras, any comments on this?

Finally she states that the practice of “breadth” is very important and the great sages all talk about “breadth control”. Any commments on this?

Thanks

Thiru